# MPI with VS2013

Tags: mpi

I have a question regarding MPI and in particular if I can run MPI with Visual studio 2013 or 2012 I saw a lot of examples but they all were shown using VS2010 with Microsoft HPC SDK 2008

If any could please tell me what exactly I need to install I would really appreciate it.

Thank you very much,
Regards

Comment: Have you tried it? MS has an MPI product that's freely available so you should be able to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of MSMPI, to my knowledge anyway, is v5 and can be downloaded from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44990

I have been using the HPC pack 2012 R2 and HPC pack 2008 versions so if they didn't change folder names, Microsoft have a tendency to do that, this is how you configure your console C++ application:

(Replace c:\Program files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012 with your installation folder!)
1) Create a new Win32 console application.

2) Project Properties ->
2a)C/C++-> Additional Include Directories Add c:\Program files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\inc

2b)Linker->General-> Additional Library Directories Add c:\Program files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\lib\i386 (amd64 if your app is 64bit).

2c)Linker->Input-> Additional Dependencies Add msmpi.lib

Your MPI application should compile now.

Since VS2013 has no MPI debugging, you need to specify mpiexec.exe directly in the debugger tab:

3a)Debugging->Command-> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\mpiexec.exe"

3b) Debugging Command Arguments-> $(TargetPath) -n 2